# Roll over image of image button

Tags: android, image, imagebutton, rollover

Can anybody suggest me how to roll over the image of the image button when clicked on it? I mean I need the sample

Thanks

Comment: can you explain exactly what you want?

Comment: write onclicklistener for image button. in that change the imageResource of image button

Comment: @vineetska...I have an image button and two different images for that. When I clicked on that particular image button, itz image should be changed. When I googled for it, I found that it is possible to have something called selectors, but I am not getting exactly the way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use selector like this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/image" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/image" />
    <item android:state_selected = "true" android:drawable = "@drawable/image" />
    <item android:drawable = "@drawable/defaultimage" />
</selector>
```

save it in yourselectorname.xml and use it in place of image...

Comment: Hi,I am able to do it, but having little problem, itz new state is not retained. I can see the highlighted image, but it returns back to previous image immediately after pressing it, is there any way to retain itz image?

Comment: Hi, instead of handling it by xml, I am doing it now pro-grammatically. Here is my code.. else if (v == btnUt) {
    Intent toUtilities = new Intent(City.this, UtilityScreen.class);
    btnUt.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mapicon));  But the problem am facing is, it sets two images for the same button. I want the previous image not to be shown when I set new image for it. Can anybody tell me the way?

Comment: <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/utilitiesicon"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/utBtn" 
  android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
 </ImageButton>

Comment: use android:background="@drawable/utilitiesicon" instead of android:src="@drawable/utilitiesicon"